# Traefik ingress does not work with cluster IP

Tags: kubernetes, dns, traefik, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I am using minikube for developing an application on Kubernetes and I am using Traefik as the ingress controller.

I am able to connect and use my application services when I use the url of the host which I defined in the ingress ("streambridge.local") and I set up in the linux hosts ("/etc/hosts"). But when I use the exact same ip address that I used for the dns I am not able to connect to any of the services and I receive "404 page not found". I have to mention that I am using the IP address of the `minikube` which I got by: `$(minikube ip)`. Below is my ingress config and the commnads that I used for the dns.

How I can connect and use my application services with the IP?

Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
    traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "true"
    traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky: "true"
    traefik.wss.protocol: http
    traefik.wss.protocol: https
spec:
  rules:
  - host: streambridge.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: dashboard
          servicePort: 9009
      - path: /rdb
        backend:
          serviceName: rethinkdb
          servicePort: 8085
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

192.168.99.100 traefik-ui.minikube
192.168.99.100 streambridge.local
```

This works: `http://streambridge.local/rdb`

But this does not work: `http://192.168.99.100/rdb` and returns `404 page not found`

Answer (score 1):

You have created ingress routes that evaluate the host header of the http request. So while you are actually connecting to the same ip, it is once with host:streambridge.local and once with "192.168.99.100" for which you did not add a rule in traefik. This is therefore working exactly as configured.

Comment: That is actually what I tried first but `kubectl` didn't accept an IP as a rule and when I wanted to apply my ingress it returned an error. This is my rule: `  - host: 192.168.99.100` and this is the error it returned: `The Ingress is invalid: spec.rules[0].host: Invalid value: "192.168.99.100": must be a DNS name, not an IP address`

Comment: I don’t understand the reason you want to access it by ip. But you should be able to achieve this using „*“ as host name (wildcard match).

Comment: I will try that but first, let me tell you why I want to access it by IP maybe you have a solution. I want to run a performance test so I need to access my application from another machine and obviously my minikube cluster IP is different than the server's network IP. One way is to use a webserver to forward any incoming request to the minikube and kubernetes but that will affect my performance test. The second solution that came to my mind was port forwarding but for that I need an IP and it is why I am trying to make this working. Any other solution will be appreciated :)

Comment: Interesting setup, please open a new question for that since it is a different scope and could be interesting to others as well.

Comment: I tried the wildcard with different configurations but all of them rejected by kubectl as invalid. I think it is not possible to use IP as a host in ingress. BTW I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56171237/5553963